# FingerPrint GUI doesn't work at login but in terminal it works

Tags: login, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

FingerPrint GUI doesn't work at login but it works in the terminal. I have ThinkPad T440, Ubuntu 18.04.2. Any solutions? Thanks.